# Postman: How to set authorization type for specific environment?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script

In Postman I have the following configuration:

I have `Basic Auth` permission for my collection.
I have an `Admin User` environment. In this environment I have `username` and `password`.
When I run my requests, the `Admin user` logs in and the request is sent.

I want to create an `Anonymous user` environment and try to access my requests without authorization (No Auth).

How do I specify an **authorization type** for a **specific environment**?

What I would like to do is in the "**Pre-Request Scripts**" check if the environment is equal to `anonymous user` and if so, do not login (using `No Auth`) !

More generally, I would like to test that my requests return an **HTTP 401 status** if I am not connected.

Any help is welcome !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set it for a specific environment but can change it from pre reqeust script

```
pm.request.auth = undefined
```

in postman you can change all request related details using pm.request object . The authroization scheme is in the pm.request.auth

so in your case you can do something like this in your pre request script:

```
pm.request.auth = pm.environment.get("user")==="Anonymous"? undefined : pm.request.auth
```

this will set auth to undefined if use is Anonymous else the default one

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for cases with the auth being inherited:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4396